# solving $12-x=\sqrt{12-\sqrt{x}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I slove: $12-x=\sqrt{12-\sqrt{x}}$?

I tried to put $t=12-\sqrt{x}$

But it got me to polynomial of 4th degree which I don't think its the idea of solving this equation.

Comment: first to the power of 2 ;then solve for x ; then check for right answer . you have to solve 4 degree equation . can you solve it by graphing ?  x=9

Comment: I can see that $x=9$ is a solution but how do you know that its the only one? And how can I graph it?

Comment: $$f(x)=12-x\\g(x)=\sqrt{12-\sqrt{x}}$$graph them , intersection(s) point are answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$$x=12-\sqrt{12-\sqrt{x}}$$
$$x=12-\sqrt{12-\sqrt{12-\sqrt{12-\sqrt{12-\sqrt{...}}}}}$$
the value of 
$$\sqrt{12-\sqrt{12-\sqrt{12-\sqrt{......}}}}=3$$
$x=12-3=9$

Comment: where you can get "this solution" ? graydad

Answer (score 3):

If $y = 12 - \sqrt{x}$, the equation says 
$x = 12 - \sqrt{y}$.  Note the symmetry.  One possibility is $x=y$ which leads to the equation
$x = (12-x)^2$.  That quadratic has two solutions $x=9$ and $x=16$, but only 
$x=9$ satisfies the original equation.

Comment: And the other possibility?

Comment: It uses the wrong square root.

Comment: I meant what is the other possibility

Comment: The other possibility is $y \ne x$, which leads to a quartic $x^4-48 x^3+840 x^2-6337 x+17424 = 0$, but it's divisible by the quadratic $(x-9)(x-16)$, leaving a quadratic quotient $x^2-23 x+121 $.  But the roots of this quadratic don't satisfy the original equation: again they're using a wrong square root.

Comment: Got it, very nice thanks